# @UniqueConstraint: Array constants have to be specified using the `Array(...)' factory method

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, ebean

I'm using the `@UniqueConstraint` annotation on a User model:

```
@Table(
    name = "users",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
        columnNames = { "building_id", "pin" }
    )
)
```

This model is part of a Play Framework 2.7 project in Java 13.

When I want to build the project, I get an error:

```
[error] /app/models/common/User.java:25:27: Array constants have to be specified using the `Array(...)' factory method
[error]     uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
[error]                           ^
```

According to [this page](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/UniqueConstraint), it should be correct. I don't understand this error.

Comment: "*According to [this page](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/UniqueConstraint), it should be correct.*" - and according to the compiler, it isn't =). Try using `uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(...) }`

Comment: That was the issue :)